Question on google sheets URL from another language, like VB
In this line, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[myworksheet]/edit?gid=0#gid=0, what does /d/ do and what other values could be there?  Same questions for /edit, ?gid and #gid.  (note-  I could not find detailed answers at: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts)
Trying to understand how to update a google worksheet from Visual BASIC.

/d basically never changes, its purpose is to indicate that what follows is the document ID.
/edit just tells you the document is in edit mode, it could be /view (viewer mode) or /copy (when the user wants to make a copy)
The gid is a unique identifier for each sheet within the document. ?gid specifies the current sheet. #gid is used to set the initial sheet displayed in the user's browser. Both of those are unique numeric identifiers.

Thanks!  Where is this documentation online in case I need to know more?

@Brooks You can check the Google Sheets API documentation. This spreadsheet.dev article can also be quite helpful.

Basically; you need to execute a POST request on VB (or VBA side) to the GoogleSheets and this request must be handled by a GET method written in the Google Sheets' script module.
